# Abstract Image & Pattern Recognition

Tags: opencv, pattern-matching, image-recognition

[image: Original Image]

This is the original Image. 
I want to recognize character[玉], which consists of various colors except green.

[image: Processed Image]

Like this.

Is there any way to achieve this?
Please help. thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify on what you mean by recognize. Do you want the software to recognize it or you want the output to contain only the characters. Your question is was too abstract.

Comment: A couple of adaptive threshold would do it. Google it.

Comment: Shin // I tried but i dont know what i should google since i dont know the keyword

Comment: Eni // Sorry for my bad. I have many fixed size tiles like that and each one has one character. What I want to do is when I take a picture one of them, the  program recognize the tile which matches best.